# Flutter break string in to two

Tags: flutter, dart

I have data string like this

```
53 > 50
```

I need to show in Text widget like 53 and 50 with >

I am able to show 53 I am doing like this

```
  Text(s.toString().substring(0, s.toString().indexOf('>'))
```

Its showing 53 value. Now I am not able to print 50. I need to show 50 in text widget how can I do this please ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is guaranteed that you will always have 3 words i.e., `53`, `>` and `50` in your srting, you can just use `String.split` method to achieve this.

The `split` method basically splits your string into parts, breaking the string whenever it reaches it's match condition, which is the parameter we pass to `split` method.

```
String a = "53 > 50";
List<String> parts = a.split(" "); //  ["53", ">", "50"]
```

If we pass, `" "` as our parameter, it will split wherever there is a `" "` in our string.

Use it in your `Text` widget like this,

```
Text('${parts[0]} and ${parts[2]} with ${parts[1]}');
```